# Tab Completion in Linux for "java" command

Tags: linux, terminal, java

I wrote a java program with vim on a Linux operating system in the terminal.
It is possible to tab complete the program name with vim by typing `vim` then the beginning of the file name `vim he` and then press `tab`. (=> `vim helloworld.java`)
But when I execute the program with the `java`command there is no tab completion for the filename.
I can type `java hellow`, press `tab` but nothing happens, I have to write out the full file name.
So why is it that tab completing file names in commands with `vim`, `mv` or `cd` works, but not with the `java` command? 
And is there a way to enable tab completion for `java` commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the shell you use.

In `bash` there must be a completion specification (compspec) for each command.

You can display the current compspec for a command name with

```
complete -p java
bash: complete: java: no completion specification
```

A simple approach (which you can put in `~/.bashrc` or as a separate file in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`) is

```
complete -o default java
```

or you can narrow possible results with something like

```
complete -G "*.jar" java
```

Comment: Pasting `complete -o default java` in the ~/.bash_profile worked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a completion for a command is a good approach, but you can force bash to do filename completion with <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> instead of the default context sensitive completion that you get with <kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: Ok, this works. It is not as comfortable as just pressing `tab` though.

Comment: Agreed...so do this until it annoys you and then add the completion from the other answer to your `.bashrc` permanently.